# send invitation using google calendar API in php

Tags: google-calendar-api

Am new in google calendar API,
Written below code for sending invitation using google API.

```
<?
require_once 'Zend/Loader.php';
Zend_Loader::loadClass('Zend_Gdata');
Zend_Loader::loadClass('Zend_Gdata_Calendar');

$setsummary="setsummary";
$setLocation="setLocation";
$event = new Google_Event();
$event->setSummary($setsummary);
$event->setLocation($setLocation);
$start_date=date();
$start = new Google_EventDateTime();
$start->setDateTime($start_date);
$event->setStart($start);
$end_date=date();
$end = new Google_EventDateTime();
$end->setDateTime($end_date);
$event->setEnd($end);
$event->sendNotifications=true;
$attendee1 = new Google_EventAttendee();
$attendee1->setEmail('xyz@gmail.com');
$attendee2 = new Google_EventAttendee();
$attendee2->setEmail('xyzx@gmail.com');
$attendees = array($attendee1,$attendee2);
$event->attendees = $attendees;      
$opt= array ("sendNotifications" => true);
$createdEvent = $cal->events->insert('********calendar id***********', $event, $opt);      
?>
```

but unfortunately it is not sending invitation.
what I have missed in this?
I just want to simply send invitation to xyz@gmail.com

Answer (score 6):

Do Not use Zend, Use Google php client lib . Below code is fully tested https://github.com/google/google-api-php-client

Go to console and create a project

https://console.developers.google.com

```
<?php
error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors', 1);
//if (!isset($_SESSION['access_token']) {
   // session_start();
//}
// If you've used composer to include the library, remove the following line
// and make sure to follow the standard composer autoloading.
// https://getcomposer.org/doc/01-basic-usage.md#autoloading
require_once 'google-api-php-client/autoload.php';

$client_id = "client_id";
$client_email = 'client_email';
$private_key = file_get_contents('Project-e7659df9db10.p12');
$scopes = array('https://www.googleapis.com/auth/calendar');
$credentials = new Google_Auth_AssertionCredentials(
    $client_email,
    $scopes,
    $private_key
);

$client = new Google_Client();
$client->setAssertionCredentials($credentials);
if ($client->getAuth()->isAccessTokenExpired()) {
  $client->getAuth()->refreshTokenWithAssertion();
}



//print_r($client->getAuth());
$service = new Google_Service_Calendar($client);

$event = new Google_Service_Calendar_Event();
$event->setSummary('Interview');
$event->setLocation('Dell');
$event->sendNotifications=true;

$start = new Google_Service_Calendar_EventDateTime();
$start->setDateTime('2015-02-14T10:00:00.000-07:00');
$event->setStart($start);
$end = new Google_Service_Calendar_EventDateTime();
$end->setDateTime('2015-02-14T11:00:00.000-07:00');
$event->setEnd($end);
$attendee1 = new Google_Service_Calendar_EventAttendee();
$attendee1->setEmail('some@someone.com');


// ...
$attendees = array($attendee1,
                   // ...
                  );
$event->attendees = $attendees;
$sendNotifications = array('sendNotifications' => true);
$createdEvent = $service->events->insert('primary', $event, $sendNotifications);

echo $createdEvent->getId();
?>
```

Comment: What is  `$private_key = file_get_contents('Project-e7659df9db10.p12');`

Comment: **Google_Auth_AssertionCredentials** has been removed. Link = https://github.com/googleapis/google-api-php-client/blob/master/UPGRADING.md#google_auth_assertioncredentials-has-been-removed

Answer (score 0):

I used the updated version of [Google PHP Client lib](https://github.com/google/google-api-php-client). Because [**Google_Auth_AssertionCredentials** has been removed](https://github.com/googleapis/google-api-php-client/blob/master/UPGRADING.md#google_auth_assertioncredentials-has-been-removed) from Google Lib.

One more thing, you have to use the [Composer](https://github.com/googleapis/google-api-php-client/blob/master/UPGRADING.md#installation-now-uses-composer) to Install the Google Library.

After creating a project on [Google Console](https://console.developers.google.com/cloud-resource-manager) with OAuth. You have to Enable **Google Calendar API**.

OAuth must have **redirect_url** which is going to be used in Calendar Token Generation. After this, on Google API Dashboard you have to download OAuth 2.0 Client JSON data and keep that file as "**credentials.json**" in your below-given Code Folder.

Use the below code in Your PHP File and Run it from Terminal (CLI).

```
<?php

error_reporting(E_ALL);

ini_set('display_errors', 1);

// If you've used composer to include the library
require __DIR__ . '/../vendor/autoload.php';

if (php_sapi_name() != 'cli') {
    throw new Exception('This application must be run on the command line.');
}

/**
 * Returns an authorized API client.
 * @return Google_Client the authorized client object
 */
function getClient()
{
    $client = new Google_Client();

    $client->setApplicationName('Calendar API Test');

    $client->setScopes( ['https://www.googleapis.com/auth/calendar'] );
    // $client->setScopes(Google_Service_Calendar::CALENDAR_READONLY);

    $client->setAuthConfig('credentials.json');
    $client->setAccessType('offline');
    $client->setPrompt('select_account consent');

    // Load previously authorized token from a file, if it exists.
    // and refresh tokens, and is created automatically when the authorization flow completes for the first time.
    $tokenPath = 'token.json';
    if (file_exists($tokenPath)) {
        $accessToken = json_decode(file_get_contents($tokenPath), true);
        $client->setAccessToken($accessToken);
    }

    // If there is no previous token or it's expired.
    if ($client->isAccessTokenExpired()) {
        // Refresh the token if possible, else fetch a new one.
        if ($client->getRefreshToken()) {
            $client->fetchAccessTokenWithRefreshToken($client->getRefreshToken());
        } else {
            // Request authorization from the user.
            $authUrl = $client->createAuthUrl();
            printf("Open the following link in your browser:\n%s\n", $authUrl);
            print 'Enter verification code: ';

            // Check Param on redirected URL, for ?code=#############  
            // you have to copy only ?code= $_GET parms data and paste in console
            $authCode = trim(fgets(STDIN)); // Get code after Authentication

            // Exchange authorization code for an access token.
            $accessToken = $client->fetchAccessTokenWithAuthCode($authCode);
            $client->setAccessToken($accessToken);

            // Check to see if there was an error.
            if (array_key_exists('error', $accessToken)) {
                throw new Exception(join(', ', $accessToken));
            }
        }

        // Save the token to a file.
        if (!file_exists(dirname($tokenPath))) {
            mkdir(dirname($tokenPath), 0700, true);
        }

        file_put_contents($tokenPath, json_encode($client->getAccessToken()));
    }
    return $client;
}

$client = getClient();

$accessToken = $client->getAccessToken();

$service = new Google_Service_Calendar($client);

$event = new Google_Service_Calendar_Event(array(
  'summary' => 'Some Text for summary',
  'location' => '800 Howard St., San Francisco, CA 94103',
  'description' => 'A chance to hear more about Your products.',
  'start' => array(
    'dateTime' => '2020-06-24T09:00:00',
    'timeZone' => 'America/Los_Angeles',
  ),
  'end' => array(
    'dateTime' => '2020-06-24T10:00:00',
    'timeZone' => 'America/Los_Angeles',
  ),
  /*'recurrence' => array(
    'RRULE:FREQ=DAILY;COUNT=2'
  ),*/
  'attendees' => array(
    array('email' => 'attendee1@domainName.com'),
    array('email' => 'attendees2@domainName.com'),
  ),
  'reminders' => array(
    'useDefault' => FALSE,
    'overrides' => array(
      array('method' => 'email', 'minutes' => 24 * 60),
      array('method' => 'popup', 'minutes' => 10),
    ),
  ),
));

$opts = array('sendNotifications' => true, 'conferenceDataVersion' => true); // send Notification immediately by Mail or Stop Hangout Call Link

$event = $service->events->insert( 'primary', $event, $opts ); 

printf('Event created: %s\n', $event->htmlLink);

?>
```

**It is working 100% for me.**