# Google Calendar PHP API Not Sending Invite Emails

Tags: php, google-calendar-api

I have successfully integrated with Google Calendar using PHP with a Service Account.

**What I can do:**

- Update the calendar event.
- Add attendees to the calendar event.

**What I can not do:**

- Send invite emails when new attendees are added.

**Here is the entire code that I use to accomplish everything so far:**

```
putenv('GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS=credentials.json');

$client = new Google_Client();
$client->useApplicationDefaultCredentials();
$client->setScopes('https://www.googleapis.com/auth/calendar');
$client->setSubject('example@gmail.com');

$service = new Google_Service_Calendar($client);

$calendarID = 'primary';
$eventID = 'XXXXXXXXX';
$event = new Google_Service_Calendar_Event(array(
    'sendNotifications' => true,
    'attendees' => array(
        array('email' => 'email1@gmail.com)
    )
));

$event = $service->events->patch($calendarID, $eventID, $event);
```

Comment: Working Solution is Here = https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21523094/send-invitation-using-google-calendar-api-in-php/59611766#59611766

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Late to the party but since there are no answers...

I've just been having this exact same problem.  Few things:

- `sendNotifications` is deprecated, you should be using [sendUpdates](https://developers.google.com/calendar/v3/reference/events/update#sendUpdates) instead.
- The optional Params don't go on the event itself - they go in the request.  So you end up with:

```
$event = $service->events->patch(
    $calendarID, 
    $eventID, 
    $event, 
    ['sendUpdates' => 'all']
);
```

Comment: That worked for me as well! Thanks. I was confused they didn't mention it in documentation :(

Comment: Although sendNotifications is deprecated it still seems to be the only method that works when using advanced calendar services with appscript in add-ons. Can anyone shed any light on this?