# Issue in sending notifications using Google Calendar API on "events.update()" function to the "attendees", after "import" of a calendar using iCalUID?

Tags: python, django, google-api, google-calendar-api, google-api-python-client

Google Calendar API using “events.update()” function doesn't send notification to the “attendees”, after “import” of a calendar using iCalUID

FYI - old_event is a "`service.events().get() response instance`" captured from an event in a different mail address abc@gmail.com.

```
new_event = old_event.copy()
new_event['organizer'] = {
        'self': True,
        'email': 'xyz@gmail.com'
        }
imported_event = new_service.events().import_(
        calendarId='primary',
        body=new_event
        ).execute()
updated_event_body = imported_event.copy()
updated_event_body['summary'] = 'New Summary'
updated_event = new_service.events().update(
        calendarId='primary',
        eventId=updated_event_body['id'],
        sendNotifications=True,
        body=updated_event_body
        ).execute()
```

Please find the code snippet on Pastebin using this [Link](https://pastebin.com/hxMUbAir)

Comment: Please format your code as code, using the proper formatting tools of SO. Also please formulate your question in the body of your question, see [Ask].

Comment: This appears to be a statement not a question.

Comment: Sorry. DalmTo. I want to know why the emails are not getting sent after importing one calendar from one account to another using "import".
Whereas the new calendar invites are working fine with the new account to which the calendar is imported.

Answer (score 0):

sendNotifications is deprecated, you should be using [sendUpdates](https://developers.google.com/calendar/v3/reference/events/update#sendUpdates) instead.

have a look at this post

[Google Calendar PHP API Not Sending Invite Emails](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51934437/google-calendar-php-api-not-sending-invite-emails)