# Adding 'sendUpdates' => 'all' to Google Calendar API (PHP)

Tags: php, google-calendar-api, google-apis-explorer

I am trying to modify the below code to add 'sendUpdated' => 'all' so all the attendees receive the email when the event is created or updated.

```
<?php
// Exit if accessed directly.
defined( 'ABSPATH' ) || exit;

/**
 * Google Calendar Synchronization.
 */
class WC_Appointments_GCal {

    const TOKEN_TRANSIENT_TIME = 3500;

    const DAYS_OF_WEEK = array(
        1 => 'monday',
        2 => 'tuesday',
        3 => 'wednesday',
        4 => 'thursday',
        5 => 'friday',
        6 => 'saturday',
        7 => 'sunday',
    );



.......full code can be found below...
```

**Full code**: https://pastebin.com/PLEwYTZV

(Above code does not belong to me and the reason it is external, because I am not able to paste everything here due to the limit.)

API Documentation: https://developers.google.com/calendar/v3/reference/events/

Comment: You should try to be more specific

Comment: Sorry, I am unable to update the question but I will explain here, and I should have been more specific.

I am trying to add a query parameter sendUpdates with value "all", but I am unable to figure out where to add it. It will send notification of the creation of the new event/updates to all attendees email addresses.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/53613880/188371 in GCal PHP API given by Google.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Had to add this to complete the url

```
$api_url = $api_url_ok.'/?sendUpdates=all';
```

Comment: its working but how to add it in a object  like ? 
{
        "summary": "Interview for job #{job_title} has been scheduled",
        "attendees": [{
          "email": interviewer_email
        }, {
          "email": candidate_email
        }],
        "start": {
          "dateTime": "#{(start_date).rfc3339}",
          "timeZone": "Asia/Karachi"
        },
        "end": {
          "dateTime": "#{(start_date+1.hour).rfc3339}",
          "timeZone": "Asia/Karachi"
        },
        "sendUpdates": "all"
      }