# How to create google calender invite through mail using php laravel

Tags: php, laravel, calendar, invite

I want step by step explaination on how to Send a calendar invite through mail using php.

I have refer 2nd answer of this link given below.
[send invitation using google calendar API in php](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21523094/send-invitation-using-google-calendar-api-in-php)
but couldn't understand the code. Please explain in brief.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Sharing your research helps everyone. Tell us what you've tried and why it didn’t meet your needs. This demonstrates that you’ve taken the time to try to help yourself, it saves us from reiterating obvious answers, and most of all it helps you get a more specific and relevant answer! See also: [How To Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask])

Answer (score 1):

Use the package `spatie/laravel-google-calendar`, a popular package to manage events on a Google Calendar.

**Example:**

```
use Spatie\GoogleCalendar\Event;

//create a new event
$event = new Event;

$event->name = 'A new event';
$event->startDateTime = Carbon\Carbon::now();
$event->endDateTime = Carbon\Carbon::now()->addHour();
$event->addAttendee(['email' => 'youremail@gmail.com']);
$event->addAttendee(['email' => 'anotherEmail@gmail.com']);

$event->save();
```

Refer the readme for detailed installation instructions.

**Link:**
https://github.com/spatie/laravel-google-calendar

Comment: Thanks but above link explains create, edit and delete any calender event. I need to know  how to send calender invite using mail.

Comment: @MonikaRana you want to send a calendar invite for a particular event right?

Comment: @MonikaRana you just need to save event as given in above example. and then attache that saved event file path in your email..

Comment: @SapneshNaik yes right. I have already create an event in my own calender UI. Now i just want to send invite to other users using their mailID's and add those events to google calender.

Comment: I have used above code, installed the package spatie/laravel-google-calendar. Now i am getting error "Argument 1 passed to Spatie\\GoogleCalendar\\GoogleCalendarFactory::createForCalendarId() must be of the type string, null given". Please help and suggest something useful.

Comment: doing these same steps, with addAttendee, i have an error: "Error 403 - Service accounts cannot invite attendees without Domain-Wide Delegation of Authority".