# Inserting events in to Google Calendar using php

Tags: php, calendar, oauth-2.0, google-calendar-api

On my website, users have a timetable of a sort. Now I want to allow users to insert those "events" in the timetable to their own Google Calendar.

I have tried doing this. I created an account and created Client ID and Client Secret. I have tried running the php files in examples folder of https://github.com/google/google-api-php-client . but none of them really work. I do get google authentication screen, but then get a blank page if "code" _GET in the url. Also I am not sure what should be a Redirect address.

How do I authenticate the user and insert an event to the authenticated user's Google calendar?

Comment: For calendar API authentication, check this link https://developers.google.com/google-apps/calendar/auth and for sample code, check this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15410720/insert-event-into-google-calendar-with-php?rq=1

Comment: Removed excess, changed wording to be more precise.